# Gradle multi repository/separately deployable projects

Tags: gradle, multi-project

I have a setup of (at least) two development projects (A and B) and a shared API

**A is core** and implements the API

**B is integration** and uses the API

The projects are separate in that I can deploy each separately. They are also in two separate repositories.

*Use case 1:*
I'm working in core and only wants to see the released version of the API

*Use case 2:*
I'm working on integration and only want to use the released version of API

*Use case 3:*
I'm developing the API and want the source of both core (A) and integration (B)

You would need three completely separate builds.
In use case 1 and 2 I would like to use a maven dependency, where I in use case 3 would like to use a gradle project dependency.

#### How would you setup your gradle builds to this (very common?) usage?

*NOTE:*

A way to think of it is when opening an IDE. In use case 1 and 2, the IDE would open the source of core and integration respectfully and using a jar-file dependency for API.
For use case 3 the IDE would have sources for core, integration, and API (all three repos open)

Comment: I think of an API as a kind of specification - maybe a set of interfaces. If A implements it, why You need to sources of A in API?

Comment: When you are working with the API (and not only one or the other side), you want to refactor among other things. (It's not an external API). If API is a misleading word, then think of abstract module whose intent is inversion of control